# Guarded Suspension in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

Based on tutorials online, I have come up with below code of guarded suspension.

```
public synchronized String method1() throws InterruptedException {
    lock = true;            

        Thread.sleep(17000);
        lock = false;
        notifyAll();    

    return "Method1";
}

public synchronized String method2() throws InterruptedException {  

        while(lock) {           
            wait();     
        }         
        Thread.sleep(3000);     

    return "From Method 2";
}
```

Above two methods are called at the same time from multiple threads.

From the above example, Does that lock variable used in the pre-condition for wait() ever be true ?

because with use of synchronized keyword, both methods are executed mutually exclusively.

Is the above example correct for Guarded suspension ?

When do we need Guarded Suspension ?

Answer (score 0):

The *Java* keyword `synchronized` used on an instance method does ensure that only one thread at a time will execute any method on that single instance having the method modifier `synchronized` as well. More precise: not only on any method but on any resource / data using the same instance as a *monitor* or *semaphore* for mutual exclusively access control.

In your example, both instance methods have the modifier `synchronized` and hence will ensure only one thread is executing code inside any of those methods at any given time.

The variable `lock` is of no use in your example, because the same method which sets it to `true` does change it back to `false`. Hence `method2` will never observe `lock` to be `true`.

Whenever more than one thread have to operate on a mutable resource and both threads should agree on the state read / operated, you have to protect this resource from racing conditions (read or modified concurrently). Otherwise the result may be different if executed by a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your implementation is incorrect because you are doing `lock = true;` and `lock = flase;`   in the same method.

In my opinion, it has to be done like below,

```
public synchronized String method1() throws InterruptedException {        
        Thread.sleep(17000);
        lock = false;
        notifyAll();    

    return "Method1";
}

public synchronized String method2() throws InterruptedException {  

        while(lock) {           
            wait();     
        }         
        Thread.sleep(3000);  
        lock = true;   

    return "From Method 2";
}
```

You have to understand that **Guarded Suspension** is a pattern when you have a situation where a **precondition** also needs to be satisfied in addition to synchronization lock being available.

e.g. when going to implement a thread-safe blocking queue, we need to put `take()` method thread on wait state if no items are available and `put` method thread also on wait state if queue is full. So this requirement is there in addition to synchronized access i.e. queue needs to be accessed in mutual exclusive way ( that is a primary requirement so you put `synchronized` on method signature ) but if queue is not in a proper state( by checking precondition variable) , you do `wait` or `notify`  etc.

You have to also keep in mind that `Thread.sleep(...)` doesn't releases synchronization lock while `Object.wait()` does.

Take a real - life example ( like that of a thread - safe blocking queue ) then we can tell if your implementation is correct or not - its not possible to tell if your implementation is correct or not ( other than pointing that `lock` shouldn't be set / reset in same method ) since there is no generic implementation of this pattern.

[Refer This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Hope it helps !!